# posting date in dd-mm-YYYY format in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have set my Date_INPUT_FORMATS = "%d-%m-%Y" in settings.py file. Below is my settings File -

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': "%d-%m-%Y",
    'DATE_FORMAT': "%d-%m-%Y",
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",
}
```

I have a model with joining date As below :

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    joiningDate = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My Serializer :

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['joiningDate', 'name']
```

Viewset :

```
class EmployeeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.EmployeeSerializer
```

This is the json I am trying to post:

```
{
    "joiningDate":"31-03-2020",
    "name":"EMpname",
```

I think I have set it up correctly but while posting I am getting the following Error:

"joiningDate": [
    "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: %, d, -, %, m, -, %, Y."
  ]

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? What did I miss? Thanks a lot in advance for your responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date-and-time-formatting), `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` must be a list:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": ["%d-%m-%Y"],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Silly me. However, I got confused due to DATE_FROMAT settings. That only takes a string. I did not check the documentation for INPUT_FORMATS. But I should have got the idea as input_formats is plural. Thanks a lot @Ivan